# How to locate user tables in another database for multisite-single-login

Tags: drupal-7

1. I am developing multi-sites with drupal.

   1. I have to take care of 10 sites and they need single login
   2. I supposed I need to create separate user database to support that
      feature.
   3. i.e 10 sites, 10 database and +1 user database.
   4. Where should I look and modify? User Module? Which lines?
   5. Normally database settings are in settings.php file .
   6. I had export the database and make and working user-database already.

Please kindly try to explain in details thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the full details of your situation but it sounds like you might benefit from one database with prefixed tables and a shared user table.

See
http://thedrupalblog.com/setting-multi-site-drupal-6-installation-shared-databases-and-single-sign and http://drupal.org/node/201673 (bit outdated but may still be helpful)

Comment: thanks for your answer,let me look at the example and test. Will reply asap . Thanks

Comment: I found an answer using your example . Not exactly like the drupal 6. But it helps .